# how to disable Content Security Policy and stay secure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

i want to disable the CSP - `app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy())` because it blocks any inline-scripts. the **hash** and **nonce** solutions (https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-script/) are too much overkill for my app.
is the [`xss-clean` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-clean) or others solutions are enough to get a regular-moderate security?

thanks :)

Comment: Just use a different CSP? There are several possible settings.

Comment: i've cheked the possible setting but there is no simple and fast way to do it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you own the CSP and are you applying it to your content? OR, is there a proxy that is doing that for you? The question here is, are you attempting to change the CSP AFTER it has been applied to the page?

Comment: "Overkill" is generally not a bad idea if you want to "stay secure".

Comment: @RandyCasburn - i dont know to answer, im still begginer.. basically the `helmet` pack has blocked my inline-scripts and i want to disable the csp to get rid from this problem without cause any big security issues..

Comment: @Pointy - you are right, so i want to understand if it is a MUST or not.. i dont know much about security

Comment: You can simply disable helmet then.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - but it will expose the web to attackers..?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have complete control using the `helmet` middleware you mentioned.

The [reference docs](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) are clear about setting up your CSP.

Once set, you can always evaluate the strength your CSP with a validator such as [this one](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com).

From the docs:

> If no directives are supplied, the following policy is set (whitespace added for readability):

```
default-src 'self';
base-uri 'self';
block-all-mixed-content;
font-src 'self' https: data:;
frame-ancestors 'self';
img-src 'self' data:;
object-src 'none';
script-src 'self';
script-src-attr 'none';
style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';
upgrade-insecure-requests
```

You can set the policy when you load up 'helmet` by following the instructions in the documentation.

For example, here is an example configuration:

```
// Sets "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self' example.com;object-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests"
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", "example.com"],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
      upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: "The unsafe-inline source list value can be used to allow inline scripts, but this also defeats much of the purpose of CSP" (from https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-script/)
is still there is a advantage to use csp in this case?

Comment: Well you can't have it both ways....right :-/

Comment: lol i understand.. sorry about the many questions, but from your experience - is it a critical security issue? or just a nice to have?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a CSP validate link you can use the validate your CSP: https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com

Comment: Security is always a good think as Pointy pointedly pointed out with his pointer :-)